# NSOperationQueue with operation block not working as desired in SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, nsoperationqueue, nsblockoperation

I have to check series of operations sequentially. but in case of any operation failed i need to call other operation before executing listed operation in queue.

```
for example:

priority 1 : Fetch all companies lookups
priority 2 : Fetch all regions
priority 3...N : Fetch all cities individually for each region
```

in each operation i pass one key which valid only for 2 hours...
suppose key was generated on 10am and i will start fetching data from server and it will take 15 mins to fetch all data completely.

but the problem is i have started fetching data on 11:59 am and during fetching information key expired. so i need to send one more request to get key and proceed further for next operations.

```
so it looks like:
priority 1 : Fetch all companies lookups with key
priority 2 : Fetch all regions (i.e. 4 Regions available) with key
   priority 3 : Fetch all cities for region 1 with key
   priority 4 : Fetch all cities for region 2 with key (here key is expire) so for taking new key need to add new operation here, which fetch new key which is valid again for next two hours.
   priority 5 : Fetch all cities for region 3 with new key
   priority 6 : Fetch all cities for region 4 with new key
```

Code which i have tried:

```
var queue = NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()
queue.addOperationWithBlock({
  callService(“http://dsn/FetchingCompanyData”)
}

queue.addOperationWithBlock({
  callService(“http://dsn/FetchingRegionData”)
  //get region List here
  for region in regions{
   queue.addOperationWithBlock({
    callService(“http://dsn/FetchingCities?region=\(region.code)”)
    //check in response if response return message like KEY_EXPIRE
    if(error){
      queue.addOperationWithBlock({
        var newKey = callService(“http://dsn/FetchingCities?region=\(region.code)”)
        setKeyToCache(newKey)
      })
    }
  }
}
}

fun callService(urlStr: String){
    let myURL = NSURL(string: urlStr)!
    var key = getKeyFromCache()
    var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: myURL)
    var errorHandling = ErrorHandling()
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.timeoutInterval = 10000.0
    request.addValue("application/xml", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("application/xml", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    request.setValue("Basic \(key)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: queue) { response, data, error in ..}
}
```

this code is not working as desire.

it adding operations in queue as below:

```
Queue:
Operation 1: Fetch companies
Operation 2: Fetch Regions
Operation 3: Fetch cities for region 1
Operation 4: Fetch cities for region 2
Operation 5: Fetch cities for region 3
Operation 6: Fetch cities for region 4
Operation 7: Fetch new key for region 1
Operation 7: Fetch new key for region 2
Operation 7: Fetch new key for region 3
Operation 7: Fetch new key for region 4
```

instead of this i want sequence of operations as below.

```
 Operation 1: Fetch companies
    Operation 2: Fetch Regions
    Operation 3: Fetch cities for region 1
    Operation 4: Fetch cities for region 2
    Operation 5: Fetch new key for region 2
    Operation 6: Again Fetch cities for region 2
    Operation 7: Fetch cities for region 3
    Operation 8: Fetch cities for region 4
```

Any help will be more appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried Bolts: https://github.com/BoltsFramework/Bolts-iOS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

resolved this issue by adding synchronous call instead of asynchronous.